# Fourier series coefficients in Matlab not negative using FFT

Tags: matlab, fft

I am trying to get the Fourier series coefficients using FFT in Matlab. They have the correct absolute value but I would also need the signs of the terms.

```
t = linspace(-pi,pi,512);
L = length(t);

S = t; % Function

c = fft(S)/L
a = c(2:end)+c(end:-1:2)
b = (c(2:end)-c(end:-1:2))*i

%The first/last b-terms should be 2, -1, 0.66, -0.50...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given how you define `t` and `S`, it looks like you are trying to obtain the Fourier series coefficients for the periodic continuous time function:

[image: \begin{align}f\left(t\right) &= t & \mbox{for } t \in (-\pi,\pi)\end{align}]

[image: plot(t,S)]

which can be evaluated analytically (or looked up in Fourier transform tables) to be:

[image: \begin{align}2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{n} \sin\left(n x\right)\end{align}]

The problem is that you do not pass a time variable when you call `fft` as it implicitly associates time "0" with the first data sample. If we plot the resulting periodic extension of the function seen by the `fft`, you should notice the time shift (compared with the `S` versus `t` plot above):

[image]

Fortunately you can undo this shift by using [`ifftshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifftshift.html). You should then also note that in order to have an anti-symmetric function (as with your original continuous time function) for which the cosine coefficients are exactly zero (or at least within the available numerical accuracy), you would need to use an odd number of samples. This should give you the following code:

```
N = 512;
t = linspace(-pi,pi,N-1); % use odd number of samples to get anti-symmetric signal
L = length(t);
S = ifftshift(t);         % ifftshift swaps lower & upper half of t, yielding S(1)=0

c = fft(S)/L;
a = c(2:end)+c(end:-1:2);
b = (c(2:end)-c(end:-1:2))*1i;
```

and the corresponding first 10 `b` coefficients (which now match your expectation and the quoted analytical result above):

[image: Plot of irst 10 <code>b</code> coefficients]

Comment: Works like a charm. Luckily this problem had a fairly simple solution so I can use it in other programming languages. Thank you for the thorough answer.